# Trying to add deriving(Show, Read) to an expression tree

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, expression-trees, deriving

I am fairly new to Haskell so it is probably something simple that I am missing but I have an expression tree that looks like this:

```
data Expression = Lit Float
                    | Add Expression Expression
                    | Mul Expression Expression
                    | Sub Expression Expression
                    | Div Expression Expression
```

And that code works perfectly fine but then when I try to add a deriving(Show, Read) so that Haskell automatically writes code to read and write elements of this type it throws an error.
This is what I am trying to do.
`Lit Float deriving(Show, Read)`

I get an error that reads error: parse error on input '|', and now the Add Expression Expression line doesn't work. Could someone point out to me what the error is here?

Answer (score 2):

the `deriving` clause has to go after the complete type definition:

```
data Expression = Lit Float
                    | Add Expression Expression
                    | Mul Expression Expression
                    | Sub Expression Expression
                    | Div Expression Expression
                    deriving (Read, Show)
```

in what you were trying, presumably

```
data Expression = Lit Float deriving (Read, Show)
                    | Add Expression Expression
                    | Mul Expression Expression
                    | Sub Expression Expression
                    | Div Expression Expression
```

Haskell comes to the `deriving` clause and assumes the type definition has finished and something else is coming after. And then the `|` character makes no sense.

You derive instances - or indeed write your own instances - for a *type*, not for individual constructors for that type.

Comment: I like to emphasise this in my own code by de-indenting the `deriving` clause (not all the way to zero, obviously). Make it visually appear to be "inside" the overall `data` declaration but "outside" the list of constructors.